# Error handling - Unstructured

Tags: sql-server, error-handling

Can someone please advise why the first transaction fails and the second succeeds, I've been stuck on this for a while now

```
GO
DECLARE @errnum AS int;
BEGIN TRAN;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Production.Products ON;
INSERT INTO Production.Products(productid, productname, supplierid,
categoryid, unitprice, discontinued)
VALUES(1, N'Test1: Ok categoryid', 1, 1, 18.00, 0);
SET @errnum = @@ERROR;
IF @errnum <> 0



BEGIN
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN;
PRINT 'Insert #1 into Production.Products failed with error ' +
CAST(@errnum AS VARCHAR);
END;
INSERT INTO Production.Products(productid, productname, supplierid,
categoryid,unitprice, discontinued)
VALUES(101, N'Test2: Bad categoryid', 1, 1, 18.00, 0);
SET @errnum = @@ERROR;
IF @errnum <> 0
BEGIN
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN;
PRINT 'Insert #2 into Production.Products failed with error ' +
CAST(@errnum AS VARCHAR);
END;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Production.Products OFF;
```

Comment: I think you have some problem with this structure. For your question, there is no reason why the second one cannot success when the first one fail. For example, primary key error. After it failed, the script continue on with the second statement. If you want to fail them all, you need SET XACT_ABORT ON; at the beginning.

Comment: What do you mean, it fails?   Do you get an error?

Comment: thanks alot everyone i figured this out